# IF condition in HTML with Java code is skipping all code of HTML and giving NULL POINTER

Tags: java, html

Working fine if sh has some value(sh=Day or Night) but when its empty/null it reads null condition and skips all the code of my html page and control goes end of the HTML file.

Question: i tried with else/ else if but still not working. please help how can i handle it without changing page layout?**

```
Goal:
When getShift() = null
then uncheck all checkboxes
And getShift()="Day"
then select radio button = Day
And getShift()="Night"
then select radio button = Night
```

Question: i tried with else/ else if but still not working. please help how can i handle it without changing page layout?**

Here is my code:

```
<% String sh= null; %>
<% sh= di.getShift(); %>
<%  if(sh==null)  {%>
        <div class="form-check-inline">
        <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" id= "Day" name="optradio" >Day
        <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" id= "Night" name="optradio">Night
        </div>
<% } %>

<% if(sh.equals("Day")) { %>
<div class="form-check-inline">
        <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" id= "Day" name="optradio"  checked>Day
        <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" id= "Night" name="optradio">Night
        </div>
<% }%> 

<%  if(sh.equals("Night"))  {%>
        <div class="form-check-inline">
        <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" id= "Day" name="optradio"  >Day
        <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" id= "Night" name="optradio" checked>Night
        </div>
<% }%>

[![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GCq2c.png
```

Comment: `sh= di != null ? di.getShift() : null;` (And you probably should not be using scriptlets and jsps in 2020).

Comment: you suggest Javascript to handle it?

Comment: No. JSP itself is largely obsolete. And scriptlets are evidence of a model 1 architecture. Try looking for model 2 jsp to see the difference. And JSF or thymeleaf for more modern alternatives to jsp.

Comment: Thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

Your best options are to either use a ternary operator or to handle the exception with a try/catch clause. Catch clauses can execute code to keep your program from breaking if it runs into a runtime exception such as NullPointer. Easy to implement too.

Since the ternary example is already listed in the comments, here's how I'd handle it with try/catch:

```
try {
    sh = di.getShift();
    //etc
} catch (NullPointer e)
    e.printStackTrace(); //optional error output
    continue;   //allows program to continue operation by iterating to next loop
```

It should probably be mentioned that this is generally not good practice. However, in your particular instance, I don't see a problem with it. Web elements can be tricky and sometimes will randomly skip values in data tables. As long as you understand why you are getting the null value, I think you can go ahead and handle the exception.

Comment: I am getting null value from DB which is expected. My DB table has existing null value which i don't want to change but column has only 3 types of values, Day/Night/NULL

Comment: In that case, why not define your string as empty ("") rather than null? You could write String sh = " " and if(sh.equals(" ") and you will no longer get this runtime exception

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that how its weird behavior is:
here is the solution:
I just removed my sh variable and directly added my property in if condition and problem solved. (took 2 days to solve but did it)

```
<%-- <% String sh= di.getShift(); %> --%>
<% if(di.getShift()==null)  {%>
        <div class="form-check-inline">
        <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" id= "Day" name="day" disabled >Day
        <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" id= "Night" name="night" disabled>Night
<% }%>
<% if(di.getShift()=="Day") { %>
        <div class="form-check-inline">
        <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" id= "Day" name="day"  checked>Day
        <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" id= "Night" name="night">Night
<% }%> 
<%  if(di.getShift()=="Night")  {%>
        <div class="form-check-inline">
        <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" id= "Day" name="day"  >Day
        <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" id= "Night" name="night" checked>Night
<% }%>
```